# Custom Object Page Layout (changes) not recognised in Scratch Org when name matches standard

Tags: salesforcedx, page-layout, scratch-org

We ran into an interesting problem that I can't find mentioned anywhere (or maybe I'm just not able to find it).

We have created 2 custom objects that have the "same" name as a standard object: Campaign Member, Opportunity Line Item. (whether that is a good idea shall be a topic for another day :-)).

When pulling source from the Scratch Org the Page Layouts for these objects were not included. Whatever change we applied to them, it would just not get picked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Labels of the Custom Objects are the same as their standard equivalents, their default Page Layouts were also named the same: Campaign Member Layout and Opportunity Line Item Layout. It seems that this caused these to be completely overlooked and not synced at all with the local project (the standard Layouts were not changed in any way).

My guess is that the changes tracked are somehow stored indexed by the API names and since Layout names can sometimes be the same this somehow clashed and caused the changes in Custom Object layouts not being tracked, i.e. the Standard objects won.

Once we updated the name of the layouts to be different from the Standard objects' layouts, there were pulled from the Scratch org without issues.